# Capturing response time

Tags: load-testing

I need to calculate request/response time as a part of a load testing scenario. I am planning to write my own coding without using any tools.

Is there a way to capture Request/response time without using the default network capture elements (Firebug, Network tabs) available in browsers?

Comment: This question is not at all clear. How are you going to write code without any tools? How you you plan to send the requests and receive the responses so you find the times? Please clarify the question, please also read the help pages on what sort of questions are suitable for Stackoverflow. At present this question risks being closed for being too broad and being off topic.

Comment: We have our own solution which captures user actions made on a browser and then replays the user action, but we are unable to capture the request/response time. 

Is there a way using C# to record network traffic?

I need to capture the URL along with the HTTP(S) methods sent, along with data sent along with the individual time 

For ex.when I hit google.com, the typical network traffic captured are URL , method-GET, Result - 302, Type- Text/HTML, received - 385B, Taken - 188ms. 

Is there way to capture like the one in the above format?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to implement on [NetGend](http://www.netgend.com) test tool. The following script will output the desired output,  the input is a list of URLs, each virtual client will randomly pick a URL and do a HTTP transaction.

```
function userInit() {
    setMaxSpawns(1);
    var urls = ["http://www.example.com/test1", 
        "http://www.example.com/test2"
    ];
}
function VUSER() {
    url = randElement(urls);
    action(http,url);
    a = getContentType(http.replyHeader);
    printf("%s,GET,%d,%s,%d\n", url, http.respCode, a, http.totalRespTime);
}

//output is like
//http://www.netgend.com/test,GET,404,text/html;,264
```

If you want to learn more, please drop a line to info@netgend.com.